# Mysql não retornando o esperado (utilizando LIKE e IGUALDADE)

Tags: mysql

Eis o código exemplo:

```
SELECT * FROM maq_dispo
WHERE ativo = '1'
AND titulo LIKE '%coladeira%' OR descricao LIKE '%coladeira%' OR valor LIKE '%coladeira%'
```

O retorno mostra todos os registros indiferentemente se o campo **ativo** apresenta o valor **1**.

Qual seria a solução?

Comment: coloque as condições OR dentro de parênteses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A única condição que deve casar com `ativo = '1'` é `titulo LIKE '%coladeira%'`, que vem ligado logo após com um `AND`. Logo, se as uma das outras duas forem verdadeiras, o `WHERE` será atendido, porque estão ligadas com `OR`.

Por isso é necessário agrupar as condições `OR` dentro de parênteses, assim apenas duas condições devem ser verdadeiras: o `ativo` ser igual a `1` **E** o resultado do parênteses também:

```
ativo = '1'
AND
(titulo LIKE '%coladeira%'
OR descricao LIKE '%coladeira%'
OR valor LIKE '%coladeira%')
```

Comment: Sim entendi. No entanto o problema que estou enfrentando é que estou utilizando o framework CODEIGNITER 2.0 e ele não faz o agrupamento de condições. Estou tentando alguma forma de fazer manualmente. Obrigado! Ajudou muito!

Comment: No Codeigniter 2.0 não há a opção de agrupar as consultas. Achei melhor fazer a atualização para a versão 3.0 do Codeigniter onde nele possui os comandos group_start() e group_end() para agrupar as consultas. Agora tudo funcionou corretamente.

Answer (score 2):

Se eu entendi, você quer todos os ativos que tenham o titulo/descrição/valor parecido com o filtro. Então faltou apenas os parênteses:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM 
    maq_dispo 
WHERE 
    ativo = '1' AND
    (
        titulo LIKE '%coladeira%' OR
        descricao LIKE '%coladeira%' OR 
        valor LIKE '%coladeira%'
    )
```